# performing fft using sounddevice numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, fft

i cant seem to figure out why my code wont produce an fft of the 
numpy array made from sounddevice.rec() 
I am able to get the code to work with an audio file, but not with
the data form sounddevice

heres my code:

```
import sounddevice as sd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

duration = 1 #sec
fs = 44100

def record():
"""records from the mic"""
   recording = sd.rec(int(duration * fs), samplerate = fs, channels =1, 
   dtype='float64')
   #waits till ur finished recording
   sd.wait(duration)
   return recording

def play(recording):
"""plays recording"""
   sd.play(recording, fs)
   sd.wait(duration)

def plot_signal_freq(ys):
   N = ys.size
   print(N)
   L = N/fs
   yk = np.fft.fft_freq(ys)
   k = np.arange(N)
   freqs = k/L
   fig, ax = plt.subplots()
   ax.plot(freqs, np.abs(yk))


while True:
   recording = record()
   print(type(recording.dtype))
   print(recording)
   play(recording)
   plot_signal_freq(recording)`
```

here is a pic of fft on a piano chord file:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ztiFt.png)

here is pic of fft on my voice recording 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ysiXB.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you provide more details about the error? You mention it works for data from a file, but not the device. How does it "not work"?

Comment: i applied it to a basic recording of a piano note and got a normal frequency response in return. When I apply it to a recording of my voice the graph is extremley colored in. I cant imagine me talking at those frequencies.

Comment: i added pictures to the original post

Comment: You should test it first with a very simple sound, such as sine wave. It's entirely possible (likely, even) that your voice contains a large range of frequencies. There may also be environmental sounds. If you can, a good test would be playing the same sound you recorded into the file. That way you can verify that you're getting the same in both cases.

Comment: thank you for the recommendation. So i tried it with a simple sin wave using middle c and got the same results I described before. I dont currently believe it is noise. It somehow appears that when I use the recording it is plotting something in the time domain and not in the frequency domain

Answer (score 1):

The recording function `sd.rec()` returns a two-dimensionnal numpy array of shape [44100,1]. The dimension 1 is related to the number of channel (here 1). To test it, type:

```
print( recording.shape)
```

Then, the dft is performed on the last dimension of length 1. Hence, nothing changes and `yk` is perfectly identical to `recording`.

To correct that, the real to complex DFT `np.fft.rfft()` can be applied to `recording[:,0]`. Furthermore, a Tuckey window can be added to temper the effet of considering a frame of a non-periodic signal as a period of a periodic signal: the discontinuity at the edge introduces spurous frequencies (spectral leackage) (see [window function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_function)).

```
from scipy import signal
...

N = ys.shape[0]
print(N , ys.shape)
L = N/fs
tuckey_window=signal.tukey(N,0.01,True) #generate the Tuckey window, widely open, alpha=0.01
ysc=ys[:,0]*tuckey_window               #applying the Tuckey window
yk = np.fft.rfft(ysc)                   #real to complex DFT
k = np.arange(yk.shape[0])
freqs = k/L
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(freqs, np.abs(yk))
plt.show()
```

Comment: wow francis thanks so much that was awesome. I just went thorught what you said and im not sure why you need to do np.fft.rfft() versus just np.fft.fft(). I also kept my k = np.arange(N). my code does not work with the rfft and changed k. But thanks again. Not a hundred percent sure why it works, but it does

Comment: You're welcome! `numpy.fft.fft()` is is the complex to complex 1D DFT: it turns a complex or real array into a complex array of the same size. Therefore, it does the trick perfectly. The `numpy.fft.rfft()` is a real-to-complex DFT: it turns a real array of size N into a complex array of size N/2+1. Hence, the size of yk is not the same and the length of `k` must be modified. As the signal is real, the coefficient of frequency `N-i` is the complex conjugate of the component of frequency `i`. The rfft does not compute the redundant coefficients, reducing computation and memory footprint.